# How can I pull only 'yesterday's' orders from Shopify API using Python. Needs to be dynamic, not static

Tags: python, datetime, shopify, shopify-api

I have successfully pulled all orders. However, my goal is to have my task scheduler run my python script to pull yesterday's or today's only orders and append the orders to an ongoing master orders list in either a SQL table or excel file. I am thinking it has to be a parameter in the URL but can't figure it out. Can anyone help with this? below is my python script URL:

```py
date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
url = "https://{API}:{Password}@{StoreName}/admin/api/2021-10/orders.json?created_at=" + date + f"&limit=250&status=any&since_id={last}"
response = requests.request("GET", URL)
```

Comment: "below is my python script url" Okay, and what happens when you try that code? How is it different from what is supposed to happen? "I am thinking it has to be a parameter in the URL " Well, what did the documentation tell you about how to specify the date? Did you try to read the documentation? Did you try to look for the documentation?

Comment: Got it to pull today's orders using the datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Here are my results though and it included an order from yesterday.. any reason why that may be? created_at
2021-11-04T19:27:16-05:00
2021-11-05T03:41:33-05:00
2021-11-05T08:08:05-05:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [shopify documentation here](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/order#%5Bget%5D/admin/api/2021-10/orders.json) about orders you can give 2 parameters:

created_at_max (Show orders created at or before date.)
&
created_at_min (Show orders created at or after date.)

So if you try these in your setup you should be fine. Example from the docs:

```
curl -X GET "https://your-development-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/orders.json?updated_at_min=2005-07-31T15%3A57%3A11-04%3A00"
```

Comment: Thanks. What would I enter after the param created_at_min=?  I see the example above but that is a static date. I need that datetime to change daily with today's or yesterday's date. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: Well, can you write code that determines yesterday's date, in the format shown in the example? (What time of day do you think you should use, in order to get the result you want?)

Comment: Python has a built-in "today" function (just google) as well as a timedelta minus 1 day (also google) which will help you. Call your script, let the system figure out the date and subtract 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose an alternative approach, one that is perhaps less prone to error than your date driven approach. First off, use your script to grab all the orders you can to ensure you are up to date. Process them, do whatever you do with orders. Now, you can easily ensure you have the ID of the latest order processed. Save this value for use!

Secondly, once a day, at your time of choosing, you run a scheduled job, that grabs all orders SINCE the last ID you previously bootstrapped or saved. That will precisely deliver to you all the orders you have not processed, since you last called this routine (once a day). Parse those orders, save the last ID processed, and continue forever. Note that this is special for the RestAPI. With GraphQL you have other methods that work to generate your lists.

You can see how this alleviates all the temporal crap of using DateTime objects, which is clearly subject to more WTF moments than anything else we typically do in easy computing.